# C++ providing default parameters to constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

In the c++ class below, I've provided default parameters to the constructor in case the user does not provide one. However, when I  for example `Point2d1 first(1, 0);` in `main()` I get an error of no matching function call. I expected the behavior to default the 3rd parameter to 0?

**.h**

```
#ifndef POINT2D1_H_
#define POINT2D1_H_

class Point2d1 {

private:
    int m_Object_ID;
    double m_x;
    double m_y;


public:
    //Point2d1(int nID);
    Point2d1(int nID, double x, double y);
    virtual ~Point2d1();
    void print() const;
    friend double distanceFrom(const Point2d1& D1, const Point2d1& D2);
};

#endif /* POINT2D1_H_ */
```

**.cpp**

```
Point2d1::Point2d1(int nID = 0, double x = 0.0, double y = 0.0) : m_Object_ID(nID), m_x(x), m_y(y)
{
    std::cout << "Constructing Point2d object " << nID << '\n';

}

Point2d1::~Point2d1() {
    std::cout << "Destructing Object" << '\n';
}

void Point2d1::print() const
{
    std::cout << "Point2d(" << m_x << ", " << m_y << ")\n";
}

double distanceFrom(const Point2d1& D1, const Point2d1& D2)
{
    double distance = sqrt((D1.m_x - D2.m_x)*(D1.m_x - D2.m_x) + (D1.m_y - D2.m_y)*(D1.m_y - D2.m_y));

    return distance;
}
```

Comment: Look up examples of how this is done on the web, then try to replicate them.

Comment: The default parameters should be specified in the .h file, not the .cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the default arguments in the member function declartion inside the class definition in the header file. Otherwise other compilation units will not know about the default arguments.

For example

**.h**

```
#ifndef POINT2D1_H_
#define POINT2D1_H_

class Point2d1 {
//...
public:
    //Point2d1(int nID);
    Point2d1(int nID = 0, double x = 0.0, double y = 0.0);
    //...
};

#endif /* POINT2D1_H_ */
```

and

**.cpp**

```
Point2d1::Point2d1(int nID, double x, double y) : m_Object_ID(nID), m_x(x), m_y(y)
{
    std::cout << "Constructing Point2d object " << nID << '\n';

}
```